# How to show a transformation is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by $T(u) = -u$. Find $T(u +v)$, then find $T(u) + T(v)$ and conclude that they are equal so that **i)** is satisfied. Then find $T(ru)$ and $rT(u)$  and conclude that they are equal so that **ii)** is satisfied. This shows $T$ is **linear**

So I know that

i) $T(u +v) = T(u) + T(v)$

ii) $T(ru) = rT(u)$

but like I don't know how to do this.

Do i just need to pick any two $2 \times 1$ matrices that i  can add together and get the same thing?? Can someone show me an example

like should I do $u = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $v = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

then like $T(u + v) = (1,0) + (0,1) = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: you don't need matrices:

$$
T(u+v)=-(u+v)=-u+(-v)=T(u)+T(v)
$$

$$
T(ru)=-(ru)=r(-u)=rT(u)
$$

if you want find a matrix that represents this linear transformation in the standard basis, than note that for
$u=[1,0]^T$ ,$v=[0,1]^T$ we have:
$$
T(u)=-u=[-1,0]^T \qquad T(v)=-v=[0,-1]^T
$$

so these two vectors are the columns of the matrix that represents $T$:
$$
T= \begin{bmatrix}
-1&0\\
0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: your letting $T= -1$ ?

Comment: No. I used the definition: $T(u)=-u$

Comment: If you want a matrix, I've added the matrix that represents $T$ to my answer.

Comment: @Yusha Not quite, $T(u+v)=-(u+v)=-u-v=T(u)+Y(v)$. Note that $T(-u) \neq T(u)$

Comment: No. I've modified my comment because you are wrong. The comment of @ZacharySelk is correct.